# Use user version of CMake Package

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I've been working on building projects a project with GoogleTest. Everything works fine when I fetch GoogleTest via FetchContent, but when I use the system version I get a linker error.

I have a user-level directory for CMake packages at `/home/alecto/.local/cmake-packages/`, and `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is set to this directory. I installed GoogleTest inside this directory, but CMake still prefers the system version of the package, even though CMake finds other packages installed inside the `cmake-packages` directory (such as Catch2).

How can I instruct CMake to prefer the version of GoogleTest installed inside `/home/alecto/.local/cmake-packages`?

Comment: Set `GTest_DIR` to where it has `GTestConfig.cmake` inside. Should be something like `gtest_root/lib/cmake/GTest`

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc:
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html

> 1. New in version 3.12: Search paths specified in the `<PackageName>_ROOT` CMake variable and the `<PackageName>_ROOT` environment variable, where `<PackageName>` is the package to be found. The package root variables are maintained as a stack so if called from within a find module, root paths from the parent's find module will also be searched after paths for the current package. This can be skipped if `NO_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH` is passed or by setting the `CMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_ROOT_PATH` to `FALSE`. See policy CMP0074.

> 3. Search paths specified in cmake-specific environment variables. These are intended to be set in the user's shell configuration, and therefore use the host's native path separator (`;` on Windows and `:` on UNIX). This can be skipped if `NO_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` is passed or by setting the `CMAKE_FIND_USE_CMAKE_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` to `FALSE`:
>    ° `<PackageName>_DIR`

So Try to set `GTest_ROOT` or `GTest_DIR`